# How to call function in NSViewController?

Tags: macos, appkit

```
class CustViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: NSTextField!
    fileprivate var selectedOptionFromMenu = ""
   
    @objc var contacts:[Person] = []
    @objc var backUpContacts:[Person] = []

    @IBAction func printCustomers(_ sender: Any?) {
```

I would like to call the printCustomers function from another class (NSWindowController). How is this coded in the NSWindowController class?

I tried the following:

```
let printAction = CustViewController.printCustomers(<#T##self: CustViewController##CustViewController#> )
```

but don't know how to code argument in this and this may be not be the way to do this?

Comment: This depends on how the window controller is related to the view controller. In any case you need the real reference in the view hierarchy, the syntax you tried won't work.

Comment: Would you explain more on a "real reference in the view hierarchy", I did some searches on this and came up empty. An example of this would be helpful.

Comment: *real reference* means the instance in the storyboard because there are outlets and actions involved. If the mentioned view controller is the content view controller of the window controller you get the instance just with `contentViewController` inside the window controller.

Comment: The window controller I am referring to is the main window where as the view controller is from a separate/different window controller/view controller. My objective is to have a main printer control action which would control which printout would be generated when a CMD-P is pressed.

Comment: Connect the IBAction to the First Responder (the red cube). Then the first object in the responder chain which implements the method will respond.

Comment: I got the answer idea to use notifications from apple developers forum.

Comment: Have you ever tried the First Responder way?

Comment: public let printNotification = Notification.Name("printNotification")
 IBAction func cashToMePrinting(_ sender: Any?) {
        print(#function)
        let printCustNC = NotificationCenter.default
        printCustNC.post(name: printNotification, object: nil)
 @objc func reactToNotification(_ sender: Notification) {
        printCustomers(Any?.self)
        }
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reactToNotification(_:)), name: printNotification, object: nil)

Comment: @vadian I had it setup originally the responder way but I need based on active window execute different code. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I used an observer to notify when to run the code in the ViewController
The following is the code I used to accomplish this:
In the main WindowController
 public let printNotification = Notification.Name("printNotification")
 @IBAction func cashToMePrinting(_ sender: Any?) {
          switch activeWindow {
        case activeView.customerView:
            let printCustNC = NotificationCenter.default
            printCustNC.post(name: printNotification, object: nil)
        default:
            print()
        }
    }
Added the @IBAction to the responder chain using toolbar print item
Then in the ViewController I added:    
 @objc func reactToNotification(_ sender: Notification) {
       // Do what you need, including updating IBOutlets
    printCustomers(Any?.self)
    }
```